# VBA to do column consolidation

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, multiple-columns

I am trying to make a consolidated financial statement, which shows all details of subsidiary and consolidated figure in the last column (I plan to use formula for total consolidated figure). I am trying to copy some specific column of worksheet (let's say column C) from selected files (each file has only one sheet with exacltly same layout, structure, and basic data) then paste it into one master sheet (newly added) to show detail of the column C from each file in column B of the master sheet from left to right. Also, I want to show the name of each file in row 1 of the master sheet, but I still can't figure out how to put it in my code.

Here is my code. So far, after I ran it in excel 2010, I found that every column are the same. I don't know what went wrong. I have more than 60 files to do this detailed consolidation. Any help woud be very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub CombineSheetColumn()
Dim DataBook As Workbook, OutBook As Workbook
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, OutSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetFiles As FileDialog
Dim MaxNumberFiles As Long, FileIdx As Long, _
HeaderRow As Long
Dim DataRng As Range, OutRng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'initialize constants

HeaderRow = 2 'assume headers are always in row 2
LastOutCol = 1

'select files
Set TargetFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
  With TargetFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
    .Show
  End With

'set up the output workbook
  Set OutBook = Workbooks.Add
  Set OutSheet = OutBook.Sheets(1)

'loop through all selected files
  For FileIdx = 1 To TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count
'open the file and assign the workbook/worksheet
  Set DataBook = Workbooks.Open(TargetFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))
  Set DataSheet = DataBook.ActiveSheet

    Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, 3), DataSheet.Cells(32, 3))
    Set OutRng = Range(OutSheet.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, 2), OutSheet.Cells(32, LastOutCol + 1))     
'copy the data to the outbook
  DataRng.Copy OutRng

'close the data book without saving
  DataBook.Close False

'update the last outbook row
  LastOutCol = OutSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column  
Next FileIdx
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what happens when you step through it looking at the source files as they are opened, and checking the columns that are copied?

Answer (score 0):

to get the filename of the source workbook, you can use:

```
Cells(32, LastOutCol + 1).value=TargetFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx).Name
```

and as for all the data being the same, you could step through and check the columns that are being copied in the source workbook in each iteration of the loop by adding a breakpoint on the line:

```
DataRng.Copy OutRng
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried adding the code, but it shows 'compile error: Invalid qualifier' to the line I added.

Comment: I have edited it, try again, should be placed **after** the line `DataRng.Copy OutRng` I think